# Deploy from self hosted agent in service with private endpoint configured

Tags: azure, version-control, endpoint, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

There is an error when pipeline tries to deploy into the Web App.

Pipeline throws this error:
##[error]Error: Error Code: ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC
More Information: Could not connect to the remote computer ("xxx.scm.azurewebsites.net") using the specified process ("Web Management Service") because the server did not respond. Make sure that the process ("Web Management Service") is started on the remote computer.  Learn more at: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC.
Error: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

The app service has configured a **private** endpoint for internal vnet usage but I would like to have the scm public accessible because the agents aren't in the same vnet.

So basically I want to combine private endpoint + scm site public acess with restrictions.

I've configured the public restricted access in multiple ways:

- service tag
- agents IPs.
- agents subnet.

It's not working, actually if I connect remotely to the agents and try to acess the scm site it returns a 403. If I configure my computer IP in the public access restriction I can acess the scm site.

Even if I configure public access without restrictions it's still not working unless I delete the **private** endpoint

All infra is in Azure.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you directly access the Azure Web App from the VM machine where the self-hosted located? To use self-hosted agent to deploy files to azure web app, you need to make sure that the vm machine can access Azure Web App.

Comment: No, I cannot. It shows a 403 althought host agent IP is added in the public access white list. If I add my computer IP it works as expected.

Comment: If you are using self-hosted agent, the agent ip should be the same as the computer IP. Are you using self-hosted agent?

Comment: Yes, it's a self-hosted agent. Logs has been turned off and now it shows more info:
Traffic was received via service tunneling but no private link identifier was provided.

Comment: error in previous message *turned on

Comment: Can you try to run the powershell script: `Invoke-RestMethod http://ipinfo.io/json | Select -exp ip` and check if the IP is same as the one you added to the whitelist?

Comment: Yes, it's the same. Seems that the traffic is done in a different way from the self hosted agents.